# How to set the id for a set of <tr>s in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a table with tr generating in a loop

```
<table>
    <div id="trresults">
    {FOR LOOP}
         <tr>
             <td>sample text</td>
             <td>sample text</td>
             <td>sample text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>sample text</td>
             <td>sample text</td>
             <td>sample text</td>
         </tr>
    {END FOR LOOP}
     </div>
</table>
```

I want to group the tr's and set a id for that. So that I used div for that, but div will not work as in table all the items should be inside td's. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: depending on what your goal is, maybe you can give all the tr's inside the loop the same class?

Comment: I want id to be set not classes

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use multiple tables, and set the ID on each table?

Comment: what code generates all the tr's? can the same code assign a unique id to each tr? please give us some details on the {FOR LOOP} part.

Comment: Hi Rajasekar, What is your reasoning for wanting an ID rather than class?

Comment: I want to append that <tr> in to another table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a TBODY element to group your rows

```
<table>
    <tbody id="trresults1">
      {FOR LOOP}
         <tr><td>for loop message</td></tr>
      {END FOR LOOP}
     </tbody>
    <tbody id="trresults2">
      {FOR LOOP}
         <tr><td>for loop message</td></tr>
      {END FOR LOOP}
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**Reference:** [Mozilla HTML Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML)

- [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/tbody)
- [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/table)

Comment: Looking at the HTML spec, it looks like you can use multiple tbody elements (but I wouldn't of thought nested directly): http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Comment: @Rajasekar no, permitted Content: Zero or more `<tr>` elements.